# ошибка переименовывания файла sass при использовании gulp-concat

Tags: gulp, sass, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

При переименовывании файла sass в style.min.css с помощью gulp-concat, в консоли выскакивает ошибка:

```
Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:
    src\sass\style.min.css
Error: expected "{".
  ╷
3 │     height: 100px
  │                  ^
  ╵
  src\sass\style.min.css 3:18  root stylesheet
```

Сам код gulpfile:

```
const { src, dest } = require("gulp");

const sass = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));

const concat = require("gulp-concat");

function styles() {
  return src("src/sass/style.sass")
    .pipe(concat("style.min.css"))
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" }))
    .pipe(dest("src/css"));
}

exports.styles = styles;
```

До этого компиляция файла sass в css проходила нормально. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: ```Error: expected "{".``` обратите внимание на то что ожидается

Comment: скорей всего что то упустили в стилях

Comment: Я поменяла строчки .pipe(concat("style.min.css")) и .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" })), и все нормально заработало.